# Testing a pipeline of sequential actions with nose

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, nose

what is the best way to test a pipeline of sequential actions with nose?

for example a pipeline like this:

```
res1 = fun1(other_params1)
res2 = fun2(res1, other_params2)
res3 = fun3(res2, other_params3)
```

At the beginning I thought to execute all tests in a class one after the other and store intermediate results in the class members. However, it seems that I this approach does not work since the results of intermediate tests are not really saved and when I try to access them (via class members) in the next test, that test will always fails.

I could pickle all intermediate results and reload them in the next test. Is there any better approach though?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do this?

```
def test_func():
   res1 = fun1(other_params1)
   assert(res1...)
   res2 = fun2(res1, other_params2)
   assert(res2.….)
   res3 = fun3(res2, other_params3)
   assert(res3...)
```

If you have a complex structure with many other_params*, you may autogenerate tests on the fly:

```
def fun1(a1):
    return a1

def fun2(a1, a2):
    return a1

def fun3(a1, a2):
    return a2

def _seq_func(p1, r1, p2, r2, p3, r3):
   actual_r1 = fun1(p1)
   assert r1==actual_r1
   actual_r2 = fun2(r1, p2)
   assert r2==actual_r2
   actual_r3 = fun3(r2, p3)
   assert r3==actual_r3

def test_all():
    test_list = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                 [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],]
    for test_vec in test_list:
        yield _seq_func, test_vec[0], test_vec[1], test_vec[2], \
            test_vec[3], test_vec[4], test_vec[5]
```

Comment: I am using something like this for the moment. However, this falls short if I have to test against several values for other_params2,other_params3 ... I would have to rewrite an independent pipeline for each parameter set, making the tests way too time consuming.